# Actionscript 3 and NativeMenus

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, menu, actionscript

If I understand correctly, the menu that comes up at the top of my app (File, View, Control, Help) is a native menu that comes from the operating system instead of as3. I don't want to have a menu there, and I am looking for ways to remove it.  Here is my current code, based on the information [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeMenu.html).

```
import mx.controls.Menu;
import mx.events.MenuEvent;
import flash.display.NativeMenu;

var menu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();

if (menu.isSupported == true)
    menu.removeAllItems();
```

I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Safe-Xchange\Development\New Project\src\Main.as(38): col:13 Error: Access of possibly undefined property isSupported through a reference with static type flash.display:NativeMenu.
            if (menu.isSupported == true)
                     ^
C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Safe-Xchange\Development\New Project\src\Main.as(39): col: 10 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method removeAllItems through a reference with static type flash.display:NativeMenu.
                menu.removeAllItems();
```

Suggestions?  Or is there a tutorial I could use?

Later note- the statement that "Static methods do belong to class itself not instances of it" makes perfect sense.  However, I am getting the same errors. I'm guessing that I am not importing the right files, but have not been able to find the correct files.  Right now I'm importing:

```
import flash.display.NativeMenu;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.NativeMenuItem; 
import mx.controls.Menu;
import mx.events.MenuEvent;
```

If I try to import "flash.desktop.NativeApplication" I get another error.

Comment: Are you using AIR?    If not, that is your problem.  NativeApplication and NativeMenu (and most classes that start with the word Native) all require AIR and don't work in FLashPlayer.

Comment: Ah- that's it. I've been avoiding AIR until the program is put together, didn't realize that NativeApplication and NativeMenu required it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your errors (and lack of tag), it looks like you are not using Adobe AIR.

The `NativeMenu` and `NativeApplication` classes (and most classes that start with the word 'Native') all require Adobe AIR and will not work in FlashPlayer.

You can [customize the context menu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f53.html) in regular flash player, but not toolbar as you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods do belong to class itself not instances of it, thus following statement is correct:

```
NativeMenu.isSupported === true;
```

Also you may disable `NativeMenu` with this:

```
stage.nativeWindow.menu.enabled = false;
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: Will check this out later today- thanks, this may be the solution.

Comment: Still get the same error using NativeMenu.isSupported == true-  "Access of possibly undefined property isSupported through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: Also get the same error with any of the following- stage.nativeWindow.menu.enabled = false;, stage.NativeWindow.menu.enabled = false;, nativeWindow.menu.enabled = false;, NativeWindow.menu.enabled = false;